# Why is this showing driver is not defined

Tags: python

Im trying to get this part of my script to upload an image from folder " zip code pics" which has subfolders named by optional zip codes

When i get to the image upload page it gives me the error driver is not defined..

What am i missing here ?

```
def picturetime():
    zipcode = get_zipcode()
    while True:
          try:
            pics = []
            for each in os.listdir(os.path.join(os.curdir, 'ZIP CODE PICS', zipcode[0])):
                name = os.path.splitext(each)
                picture_name = os.path.join(os.curdir, 'ZIP CODE PICS',zipcode[0] , each)
                picture_name = os.path.abspath(picture_name)
                pics.append(picture_name)
            if pics:
                picture_name = random.choice(pics)
                driver.find_element_by_id('plupload').send_keys(picture_name)
                print('[zip code image] clicking on save_link after picture')
                sleep(10)
```

Comment: In the code you have provided, you haven't defined `driver`.  Python seems to think you haven't defined it at all.

Comment: Its defined up top ... it opens up firefox goes thru all the steps all the way until this part

Comment: It's not clear what `driver` is or where it's defined in your code.  It looks like it's not available inside the `picturetime()` function scope, even if you've defined it elsewhere.  Try passing `driver` into `picturetime()` as an argument and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: When i do that it seems to just open up another instance of firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def picturetime():
    global drive
    zipcode = get_zipcode()
.......
.......
```

Comment: That worked to get past the driver issue... but now its not uploading the image... it just opens up the browse button basically which opens the mini window to go find your pic ... i need it to upload the image as well

Comment: “opens the mini window to go find your pic” means the way you upload your image did not use "picturetime()". Show me more code.